# Triple even-sized windows in Emacs on startup

Tags: emacs, configuration, window, split, size

I would like to set up Emacs to maximize (or specific size) and split my window horizontally into three equally sized frames on start up.

I have found other questions that are similar but not quite, [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097321/specify-window-layout-in-emacs-on-commandline) and [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987760/how-to-change-size-of-split-screen-emacs-windows).

Thank you.

EDIT: Maximize, not fullscreen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have equally sized windows you can use the command `balance-windows` (bound to `C-x +` for interactive use).

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is what I come up, There will be more elegant way to it. Nonetheless this does you want.

```
  (defun split-windows-even-3 ()
    "split into 3 evenly"
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (let ((ps (window-width)))
        (split-window-horizontally (/ ps 3))
        (other-window 1)
        (split-window-horizontally (/ ps 3)))))

  ;;; ADD HOOKS to startup
  ;;  split three
  (add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'split-windows-even-3)

  ;; Fullscreen 
  (add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda ()
                                  (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'fullboth)))
```

UPDATE: now its working emacs23 and emacs24

Comment: @NiklasHansson It does for me on Emacs 24., which version of emacs you are using

Comment: Ah, that's the thing. I am on Emacs 23. Sorry!

Comment: @NiklasHansson changed the function would you try now

Comment: Thank you for your time (+1), but I will still go with @Nicolas Dudebout's simpler answer.